# Taking time off to switch technologies/job

Tags: career-development, negotiation, career-switch, hiring, time-off

I'm currently planning a career move, and would love some feedback on my particular situation.

I've currently got about 10 years experience working on C#/.NET in various companies, with experience in things ranging from code design and unit testing to .NET low-level concepts and security. I have found these pretty challenging and interesting.

But lately I've developed quite an interest in lower level languages, particularly C, C++ and Rust. I'm really amazed at the diversity of solutions that these sorts of technologies can be used in, while I find that C#/.NET is mostly used to build web or desktop apps/systems that automate business processes.

Currently, I'm trying development in these lower-level languages during my free time, but I find that I'm just not able to progress as fast as I want, nor am I as fresh and energetic to putting in another 2-3 hours daily for it after my regular work day.

So, I'm planning on taking 6 months to 1 year off work, to fully invest in self-study, working on some personal projects in this new tech and maybe even contributing to some open-source projects. I've got a plan in order to avoid the risk of taking time off and just wasting time.

Another reason I'm doing this is to avoid the "need" to start as a junior in the new tech. I guess the main concern future employers will have is what I've been doing in that time gap, for which I believe I'll have a proper response: working on personal and open source projects in C and C++.

I wonder if I am committing some sort of career suicide. I'm fairly confident in my plan, but would love to see some other opinions of the community.

**How will such a decision potentially affect my return to a regular job in the new technology?**

Comment: Hello, disposabledev, and welcome to the Workplace. Your question is a good one but it's gonna be closed as it stands (see votes for details). The meat of your question is _how do I change specialty without starting from scratch_, I think it's worth rephrasing to something like that rather than asking us if your plan is a good idea.

Answer (score 3):

> I'm really amazed at the diversity of solutions that these sorts of technologies can be used in, while I find that C#/.NET is mostly used to build web or desktop apps/systems that automate business processes.

Perhaps it's just based on area, but the higher level languages (C#, Java, etc.) certainly do have more "interesting" applications as well. I realise this isn't the main point of the question, but I'd certainly keep an eye out for more interesting opportunities in what you're already familiar with - something may come along that surprises you.

> So, I'm planning on taking 6 months to 1 year off work, to fully invest in self-study, working on some personal projects in this new tech and maybe even contributing to some open-source projects.

Unfortunately, I'd tend to caution against this for the following reasons:

- You'll have a year or so's gap in employment which may raise questions on its own (you may say that you're just "self-studying", but employers may think you did a bad job in that time that you don't want to come to light in a reference, or something like that);
- Personal projects that aren't open source are good personally, but hard for a company to verify - they will be seen of little, or no value;
- Contributing to open source projects is a nice addition, but certainly not a replacement for industrial experience;
- At least in my experience, you're entering into a field where there's fewer jobs available than the one you're currently in.

The "normal" route I'd suggest if you want to switch fields, and not jump back to a junior level role, is to obtain certifications, where they exist (I can't find any widely accepted certification for Rust, for example.) This will at least demonstrate a level of competence in languages that you have no direct experience of. However, I'd still caution against taking any large amount of time off work to obtain these certifications for the reasons outlined above.

Comment: Thank you for the detailed response. As far as why I want to switch to C++, the main reason is I'd like a change and a change into something a lot more low-level than .NET. There may be interesting projects in .NET (not in my area), but nothing I've seen beats what I frequently see on cppcon presentations. But the main reason is I want to try my hand at something low-level.

Comment: As far as the risks you outline:
- I'm hoping that since I already have 10 years of working experience, with plenty of references from past jobs, they'll not suspect that in that 1 year I did something horrible. But I guess I can't stop that.
- the personal projects I'll be working on will be made public/open-source.
- I know industry experience is better, but as I said, I'd like to avoid jumping back to a junior position and starting over (which I don't even feel would be fair for me)

Comment: - I know there are more jobs in .NET than in C++, but I'm hoping a lot more of them are more interesting. Plus, I'll refer to the main reason I'd like to switch: I'd like to work at at lower level of abstraction.

Comment: Ultimately, I don't know how else to do this. There is too much information to go over in just my spare time and am usually too tired at that point, so I'm hoping a year off isn't that bad. I keep reading about other developers taking time off. Some warn that this is career suicide, others that it's ok. I'm not sure what to believe

Comment: And it just seems very pessimistic of our industry, if one can't take 1 year off without future employers jumping to the worst conclusions about what you did in that year. Is it really that bleak out there? Am I just being unrealistic?

Comment: Career suicide is too strong; there are undoubtedly some employers that would listen to what you say about what you've been doing, believe it, and value it highly. Doing this certainly isn't going to make you unemployable - but it may well mean you take a year off to study hard, sacrifice a year's salary, and struggle to end up with a job that pays similar to what you get now at the end of it. To me it just doesn't seem like a good trade off, but if you've taken on board what others have said and still feel that you'd be happier / it's a better long term choice then I wouldn't try to stop you!

Comment: Thanks for the advice. Another way I'm planning on making sure I can prove that I've not been wasting time in that year off, is with consistent commits to my github repo. I hope it doesn't come to that, but that should prove I've been active, I guess.

Comment: @disposabledev The problem isn't so much that you'll have evidence to back yourself up and to prove your point - it's more that your CV may not pass the initial "screening" if they smell something that doesn't seem quite right, and at that stage they're very unlikely to invest much time in terms of digging around for Github commits.

Comment: Very good point. I didn't think of that

Answer (score 1):

I would avoid taking a break for a couple of reasons:

- Long gaps look bad on resumes
- Learning on your own is not nearly as valuable as learning on the job

With that said, there are a couple of good options available to you.

**Find a company willing to hire C# developers to do C++ work**

Many smart companies will hire experienced talented developers, regardless of what technology they have experience in.

A talented developer who wants to learn a new tech stack will come up to speed and be productive quickly.  They will easily surpass a bad developer who has a lot of experience in the same tech stack.

**Find a company that uses multiple languages/development environments**

There are a lot of companies who need skills in multiple languages/environments.  They need people who are interested in/capable of having a diverse skill set.

For example, my current company has a user interface application written in C#/WPF that talks to hardware that is running a C++ application on Linux.  My previous company had a large legacy C++ codebase that was wrapped in a modern C#/WPF application.

Answer (score 0):

It seems to be a good idea to switch to new technologies and it will probably open new opportunities to your career, independent of the specific area.

I'm passing through a similar situation, where I was back-end developer and now I'm learning and practicing front-end development, with the idea to be a full-stack developer. There is nothing wrong to dedicate time to yourself and grow your own skills.

In my humble opinion, all people should do that.

It is important to say that I've started my development career with **Java SE**. After four long years of learning, working and practicing, I've changed to Node.js. I'm now employed in a company that uses, in most of the cases, Node.js as back-end structure.

Don't be afraid to evolve. You should never be afraid to evolve.

I believe that if you have financial conditions to keep your life safe until you get a new job, it will be a good idea to dedicate yourself (full time, on the break). Although, if you have full dependence on the current job salary, you will need to analyze your options to don't take dangerous risks. But, in general, I believe it will be good (to learn full time on the break).

Also, before starting to learn in full time, I recommend you to analyze if the city you live in have opportunities and is hiring developers on the programming language you currently want to learn. Or, depending on your personal situation, if you are available to travel to another place to work with the language you did chose.

I guess you know but is always good to reinforce that when you start programming a different language, you will not start as a Master, or Senior. You will need to acquire experience through time while you will getting better. You also should be prepared for a different salary.

**Important to don't forget**:
- Analyze your financial risks
- Check the hire opportunities for the language you want
- Stay prepared for an initial different salary

Comment: I think this answer can be made more helpful if it addresses the issues of "How will such a decision potentially affect my return to a regular job in the new technology?" The OP is talking about taking time off to be proficient in the new tech.

Comment: @ValarMorghulis I said it will probably open new opportunities.

Comment: But you're not sure. The OP is asking about taking time off to learn new tech before switching. If you have taken time off to do the same, please mention it. There is some risk involved.

Comment: @ValarMorghulis It is not possible to be sure. Every person can be found in a different situation. For me, it works. I learned and I switched to Node.js in a new job. There are facts in his life that should be analyzed to be near to the truth (in an example, if he has a family to sustain).

Comment: Can you please answer the question on whether taking time off to learn new technologies is a good move?

Comment: @ValarMorghulis I said "It seems to be a good idea to switch to new technologies"

Comment: Of course. And I agree. The OP also agrees. But would it be a good idea to do so on a break? That is the question.

Comment: @ValarMorghulis Hmm I get the point, hehe. Well, I believe that if you have financial conditions to keep your life safe until you get a new job, it will be a good idea to dedicate yourself (full time, on the break). Although, if you have full dependence on the current job salary, you will need to analyze your options to don't take risks. But, in general, I believe it will be good (to learn full time on the break). Do you have a similar idea?

Comment: Good that you clarified. Can you please update the answer to mention this? Also, please consider answering how the OP will plan to get back into the job market with their new skill set once they come out of a break, because in my experience, one's market value is high only when one is currently on a job. :) And therefore, the OP will have to become a master in the language and ace interviews before negotiating a senior position's salary.

Comment: @ValarMorghulis Yes, I will do that. I'm new here, can you explain to me what OP exactly means?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/72708/discussion-between-pitter-and-valarmorghulis).

Comment: Thank you for the responses guys. As far as planning, I'll of course only do this with ample financial support for the full year, and some extra time, depending on how long it will take me to get back into the job market.

Comment: And of course, I'm not expecting to get back into the market as a senior in C++. But at least as an intermediate I'd expect to be evaluated. Hope it's not wishful thinking

Answer (score 0):

I don't think we can answer the question, but I think there is a way to go about finding the answer.

Start interviewing, inquiring other companies and asking people work in this area.

Good developers are hard to find regardless of their stack experience. If you don't want to be a junior a year from now, are you willing to be a junior until then?